# How to avoid temporary files in doing search/replace string in files

Tags: replace, grep, temporary

I was trying to search and replace string in files using command:

```
grep -rl oldtext . | xargs sed -i 's/oldtext/newtext/g'
```

The problem is, it reports error that temporary file $#^%$^$ cannot be opened: permission denied.

The command was run with sudo, so it seems the temporary file was generated when grep command is executed, but sed cannot replace the string in that temp file since it's being opened.

I tried to specify the file type to *.html but still the same error:

```
grep -rl oldtext *.html . | xargs sed -i 's/oldtext/newtext/g'
```

I know using find can avoid the issue:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/oldstring/newstring/g' *.html {} \;
```

Just curious how to avoid this issue with grep command. Thanks!

Comment: sed is creating a temp file whether it's called directly from find or not. The `-r` option for grep is some syntactic sugar that the GNU guys introduced contrary to the UNIX philosophy (what's next for GNU grep - options to sort output? options to translate characters? options to do math?) so it should never be used when`find` already exists to find files recursively and does it well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am a bit confused by it - seems you meant -r option should never be used with grep because find command can handle searching quite well? Just want some confirmation.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The UNIX command to recursively find files is named, somewhat obviously, `find`. None of the GNU grep arguments to recursively search for files should ever be used because their existence violates the UNIX philosophy of each tool doing one job and doing it well, and it typically leads to a horrible mess of convoluted arguments with file-finding arguments mixing in with regexp-within-file-finding arguments. `grep` literally means `g/re/p` which are the `ed` commands to Globally search within a file for a Regular Expression and Print the matching string.